# Taking fourier transform of a function using symbolic variable

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, continuous-fourier

MATLAB failed to compute the `fft` of this function:

```
syms t;
x= 1/(1+t^2);
X= fft(x)
```

And threw this error:

> Undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Why didn't it take the Fourier transform of the symbolic variable? I think it should because we may want to obtain the result as a symbolic value.

I also tried to solve the problem with non-symbolic variable.

```
t= -10:0.01:10;
x= zeros(2001);
x= 1/(1+t.^2);
fft(x)
```

this time my error is:

> Matrix dimensions must agree.

However, they have the same dimensions.
Where is my fault?

Comment: Please don't modify the question to say you got an answer, I rolled your edit back. Accept the answer which got you the solution and upvote any proper answers.

Answer (score 1):

The [documantation on `fft`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) says:

> Y = fft(X) computes the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of X using a fast Fourier transform (FFT) algorithm.

Symbolic functions are continuous, not discrete. Hence, the algorithm fails.

With regards to your second question: use element-wise operators, by adding a dot:

```
t= -10:0.01:10;
x= zeros(2001);
x= 1./(1+t.^2);
fft(x)
```

MATLAB complains about matrix dimensions, because you are trying to divide a scalar (i.e. a `1 x 1` matrix) by a vector of length 2001. element-wise division solves that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/315950

> FFT is a method for *numerical* discrete Fourier Transform (DFT).

Basically, what you're asking doesn't make sense. FFT is designed to work numerically on discrete data (a sequence of numbers).

What you want is the *Fourier Transform* of your symbolic expression.  For that, I believe you want [`fourier`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fourier.html).